# Outlook 2016 truncates folder names when there is no need

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Since upgrading our Office 365 to 2016 I have noticed that some folder names are  truncated even though there is plenty of space and other, longer, folder names are in full. Anyone else seen this and has anyone solved it?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I experience the same issue. Currently, no workaround available. Strange thing is that I have it on Windows 10 but no problems on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Can you add an image to show what you are experiencing?

Comment: Added a screen shot. You can see some long folder names that are perfectly OK whilst short one are truncated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen if you have never clicked on the folder/sub-folder. Once you click on the respective folder, the full name will appear.

Weird